# Apex Test.createStub() throwing error for methods with parameter of type: Time

Tags: apex, unit-test, stubapi

I'm trying to stub an apex class that has a public method with a Time type parameter. I've modified the code slightly from [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm) to include a Time parameter:

```
public class DateHelper {   
    // Method to stub    
    public String getTodaysDate(Time t) {
        return Date.today().format();
    }
}
```

```
public class DateFormatter {    
    // Method to test    
    public String getFormattedDate(DateHelper helper) {
        return 'Today\'s date is ' + helper.getTodaysDate(null);
    }
}
```

The classes DateFormatterTest, MockUtil, and MockProvider remain the same as in the link to the documentation above.

When I run the test in DateFormatterTest, I get this error: `System.TypeException: @Override specified for non-overriding method: String DateHelper__sfdc_ApexStub.getTodaysDate(com.force.swag.soap.Time)`.

Why is it throwing this error when I add the Time parameter? Is there any way to stub an apex class with a method that includes a Time parameter?

Comment: What happens if you provide a time variable to the method?  if you just provide null, it's untyped and I think I've had problems with this in the past because it doesn't know it's the method that passes in the time.  e.g. `Time myTime; return 'Today\'s date is ' + helper.getTodaysDate(myTime);`

Comment: @NickCook same error :(

Comment: What version of the API are you using for your classes?

Comment: I suggest you have a local `Time` or `time` that is masking the required type. What if you change the parameter type to `System.Time` so the declaration is no longer ambiguous?

Comment: @NickCook I'm using API version 55.0

Comment: @PhilW If you're suggesting that I have a 'Time' Apex class, I do not. Although weird thing I just found out: This fails in a Trailhead playground, but passes in a Developer sandbox. I may creating a fresh trailhead playground and see if it passes there.